# Cardinality of the largest clique in an octahedron

Tags: graph-theory

Is the largest clique in an octahedron is 3?
I have no idea how to deal with this question. QQ

Comment: Is that a crying emoticon, quick question or a _I quit_ ?

Comment: Haha! I'm crying when I asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Pick any face of an octahedron. This is a clique with 3 vertices.

Now, suppose that there exists a clique with 4 vertices. Fix one of these, call it $V_1$. Then, the other three vertices are exactly three vertices adjacent to $V_1$. And you can visualize that these are not adjacent each other: hence they do not form a clique.

Comment: Oh! I got it! Thanks! So just use contradictory to prove it? BTW. Is there any method to get exact largest clique cardinality in any graphs?

Comment: @J.Hsieh I think this is an NP-Hard problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Comment: Okay ! Thanks a lot